# ffmpeg / python script - is it actually doing anything?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, python

I downloaded the following script - it is not my own work; it came with another Python script which scans through a folder of Rocket League gameplay videos, looking for moments where a goal has been scored (using tesseract-OCR), and then logs the clip filename and frame into a csv file called "detected.csv".

That part has all worked now I've figured it all out!  It is the second part, this script is supposed to read the "detected.csv" list of files and frame numbers, to then trim and create the new video clips and output them to a folder.  The code looks like this:

```
import ntpath
import os

detectedGoalList = []
f = open("detected.csv", "r")
for x in f:
    tup = x.replace("\"[", "").replace("]\"", "").split(", ")
    print(x)
    detectedGoalList.append([tup[0], tup[1]])


for dg in detectedGoalList:
    print(dg[0])
    input_file = "\"{}\"".format(dg[0].replace("'", ""))
    output_path = "../clips/" + ntpath.basename(dg[0]).replace("'", "").replace(
    ".mp4", "").replace("Rocket League®_", "").replace("Rocket League™_", "").replace("Rocket 
    League_", "") + ".clipped.mp4"
    start = (int(dg[1]) - int(30 * 10)) / 30
    if start < 0:
       start = 0
    end = (int(dg[1]) / 30) - 3
    duration = end - start

    os.system("ffmpeg -ss {} -i {} -t {} -c copy {}".format(start, input_file,
                                                        duration, output_path))
```

The script runs instantly and returns no errors. It doesn't log anything to the terminal. It doesn't output any new clips. I have 5 mp4 files in the "clips" directory that match in the csv file exactly. The "detected.csv" file contains the following:

```
"['K:/Gameplay Videos/Rocket League/goals/clips\\goal(2).mp4', 1750]"
"['K:/Gameplay Videos/Rocket League/goals/clips\\goal(28).mp4', 1200]"
"['K:/Gameplay Videos/Rocket League/goals/clips\\goal(3).mp4', 3350]"
"['K:/Gameplay Videos/Rocket League/goals/clips\\goal(4).mp4', 3050]"
"['K:/Gameplay Videos/Rocket League/goals/clips\\goal(5).mp4', 3500]"
```

So I'm pretty sure that the final ffmpeg line is the culprit.  I understand basic command line ffmpeg syntax but when it's part of Python code and variables I just can't figure it out.  I see reference to the number "30" a lot - maybe the guy who wrote this had 30fps videos as his source (they were after all Playstation replays), I have 60fps videos. I've tried changing those numbers to 60 to no avail.

Comment: Is the `print(x)` line producing the output you expect? How about `print(dg[0])` ? Did you check that `start, input_file, duration, output_path` all have the values you expect?

Comment: "I have 5 mp4 files in the "clips" directory that match in the csv file exactly. " I don't think I understand. How are these .mp4 files not the "clips" you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Karl, no, none of those print commands are doing anything now, before they were. As before I got to this stage I did have the code running and throwing an "Unable to find a suitable output format for" error - due to me not having the videos in a specific folder called "clips" as specified in the output_path. When I was getting that error the code was looping through all video files as expected, and the print(x) result (I had put that in there myself before whilst trying to debug the earlier error) outputted each video filename as expected.

Comment: "I have 5 mp4 files in the "clips" directory that match in the csv file exactly. Here I'm just confirming that the csv file is correctly listing the correct video files - i.e. the source data in "detected.csv" contains the right information. They are not the clips I'm looking for, these are the source videos, this script is supposed to be trimming and creating new video (mp4) clips from the ones listed in the csv file as far as I know.

Comment: Could you explain how I can check whether start, input_file, duration, output_path etc values are correct? If I can't get them to print to the terminal I don't know how else to check what values they are being given. Sorry I am a novice with Python! :-(

Comment: "Hi Karl, no, none of those print commands are doing anything now, before they were" What does "before" mean? What exactly has changed since then? Anyway, it is not possible that you see no output from `print(x)` as long as `detected.csv` still contains those lines. You should double-check that said file hasn't been blanked. Alternately: maybe it's re-written by the first script? In which case, maybe the output is variable? Did you consider the possibility that the video in the source folder currently just doesn't show any goals being scored?

Comment: I seem to have it working, looks like I need to have run the 1st script again within the terminal if the 2nd script is to work, it must be saving something in memory around "detectedGoalList".

Comment: More likely it is creating/fixing the `detected.csv` file.